# Kong Chart installation Kubernetes cluster unreachable error

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kong

I'm trying to install Kong for Kubernetes using Helm charts using below wiki.
https://github.com/Kong/charts/blob/main/charts/kong/README.md

I'm getting the following error. Is there any other mirror available for it?

```
$ helm install kong/kong --generate-name --set ingressController.installCRDs=false
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://192.168.64.2:8443/version?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.64.2:8443: i/o timeout
```

Comment: Any logs on K8S ? seems a port forwarding issue

Comment: The error is telling you that you / helm cannot communicate with your Kubernetes API server. It doesn't really have anything to do with Kong.